# ReferenceError: elgg is not defined

Tags: .htaccess, php-ini, elgg, ioncube

Till yesterday my site was running well.

I want to use ion cube loader so, I have changed php version from **5.4 to 5.5**,
in php.ini

```
zend_extension=/opt/ntphp/php52/lib/php/extensions/Zend/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so
```

and in .htacess file

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/USERNAME/public_html/myfolder
```

then it started giving me "ReferenceError: elgg is not defined" form here

```
elgg.config.lastcache = 1463814175;
elgg.config.viewtype = 'default';
elgg.config.simplecache_enabled = 1;
elgg.security.token.__elgg_ts = 1463820371;
elgg.security.token.__elgg_token = '921400a07830ef8c7d5ccdb2640f440d';

//Before the DOM is ready, but elgg's js framework is fully initalized
elgg.trigger_hook('boot', 'system');
elgg.session.geopositioning = {"location":"","latitude":0,"longitude":0};
```

Even checked after reverting all the things but the error is same.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReferenceError: elgg is not defined` is likely because PHP is polluting JS output.

- Did PHP error reporting values change during the upgrade? Did you try disabling error reporting in Admin > Advanced Settings
- Did you flush simplecache?